# How to iterate files recursively in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Is it possible to iterate files in Groovy recursively? Currently I'm using `FileUtils.iterateFiles()` from Apache `commons-io`, but maybe there is some Groovy-native alternative for the same?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Absolutely, you should check the documentation for File in Groovy. It's available [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html) and gives you a few different helper methods to iterate recursively over a file structure.

```
// Simplest possible example, iterating over each file in every subfolder
new File('.').eachFileRecurse { println it.name }
```

Comment: Closure can be main advantages in Groovy :)

Comment: I'm leaning more and more towards the additions to the JDK class library being among the most important parts of Groovy. Many of them would ofc not be possible without closures. I'd urge any developer learning the language to go over the GDK again and again until they feel they have a good picture of whats available. There's so many unexpected goodies in there. [Reading material](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/)